# Change nginx autoindex output format

Tags: xml, nginx, mod-autoindex

I want to share folder contents over http. I've installed nginx with autoindex on and configured it to my folder. The problem is it takes me html file with file/folder list, but I want some kind of xml with same information.

Is it possible to do it using standard nginx tools, or should I implement some script to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to involve some scripting to make it work. Most what you can get with nginx configuration is custom [footer and header](http://wiki.nginx.org/NgxFancyIndex).

By the way, developers [looks forward](http://nginx.2469901.n2.nabble.com/Autoindex-module-extension-patch-td7259016.html) to adding xml index module to nginx.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from version 1.7.9 you can use:

```
autoindex on;
autoindex_format xml;
```

See the docs: http://nginx.org/r/autoindex_format

Comment: Just to clarify - I'm assuming you mean 'version 1.7.9 of the autoindex module'. As of Jan 2015, the latest version of nginx is 1.4.7

Answer (score -1):

sudo apt install libnginx-mod-http-fancyindex

> fancyindex on;